# Find element hasClass and modify the previous one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element, the last one, which has step-active class. Now, I want to write a method, which looks for the element, which has this class, then remove this class and add it to the previous one.
Then I call this method if a button is clicked.

I have the following piece of HTML code:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 step-panel" style="padding-right: 0">
    <div class="step container-fluid">
        <p>4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
        <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="step">
        <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="step step-active">
        <p>1</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my js:

```
function indicateStep() {
        $('.step').find().hasClass('step-active');
        $(this).removeClass('step-active');
        $(this).prev().addClass('step-active');
}
```

I can't get it work, could anyone tell me why and suggest any solution?

Comment: `$('.step-panel').find('.step-active')...`

Comment: How about something like `var elem = $(".step-panel").find(".step-active");`?

Comment: Already some answers on how to do it - reason what you've got isn't working is because you're looking for a div with class `step`, then looking at it's children with `find` for one with class `step-active`, which obviously won't be found

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick

```
function indicateStep() {
    $('.step.step-active')
    .removeClass('step-active')
    .prev()
    .addClass('step-active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
function indicateStep() {
    $('.step-active').removeClass('step-active')
        .prev('.step').addClass('step-active');
}
```

Basically, this finds the current `step-active` element, removes the `step-active` class, goes to the previous `.step` element, and adds the class to that one.

One of the reasons your code wasn't working, was because you didn't save `$('.step').find().hasClass('step-active');` to a variable. `$(this)` isn't the element you need, there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really solved the problem. I wasn't sure which one should I catch, the .step-panel or the .step.

Comment: I used `$('.step-active')` because that's the exact element you want to modify.

Comment: I'm wondering how can I find an element which has a particular class. I thought it is a good solution in this case if I can identify the element with the class.

Comment: That's exactly what `$('.step-active')` does. It selectes the element that has `step-active` as class. (The `.` in there tells jQuery to look for a element with the following string in it's class)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're calling `indicateStep` on the result of a button click.

The problem is with the

```
$('.step').find().hasClass('step-active');
```

line, and the fact you're not using the result of the attempt to find it.

Here's a verbose version for clarity:

```
function indicateStep() {
    // Find the active step and remember that element
    var step = $(".step.step-active");

    // Remove the class from it
    step.removeClass("step-active");

    // Add it to the previous one instead
    step.prev().addClass("step-active");
}
```

And the one-liner version:

```
function indicateStep() {
    $(".step.step-active").removeClass("step-active").prev().addClass("step-active");
}
```

Comment: The one line version looks more engaging to me:)

Comment: @photoscene: Yeah, I just include the verbose version for clarity. :-)